# How to read from Iso file?

Tags: linux, iso-image

Are there any linux command which lets me to read Iso file byte by byte without mounting?

Comment: An ISO file is a file, you can use all manner of Unix tools such as `cat` to read it. You should elaborate more about your intention in order to getting better help.

Comment: What do you mean byte by byte?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I think he is trying to extract one file from ISO and read it. Ugur, am I correct?

Comment: I just want to read first bit of the iso. is it 1 or 0? I just need that.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: I can read as a string by using getline command. I couldn't read it as a byte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dd if=file.iso bs=1 count=1|tr '\000-\177\200-\377' [0*128][1*128]
```

Answer (score 1):

`cat` and `read` is OK.
You can do sth. like:
`cat file.iso | while read -n 1 x ; do .. here do something with one character (like echo "$x") .. ; done` 
 for more info use:
`man cat` `help read` `help while` 
Or you can use C `man 2 read`

Answer (score 0):

An ISO is just a container file, much like a zip file. Most compression utilities (such as 7-zip for windows) can extract the files contained in the ISO to your hard drive for you.

Answer (score 0):

To read some files from ISO, you can use `isoinfo` command (from `genisoimage` package).

For example, to list files:

```
isoinfo -i somefile.iso -l
```

To print specific file to stdout:

```
isoinfo -i somefile.iso -x /path/to/filename
```

> `-i filename`     Filename to read ISO-9660 image from

> `-x pathname`     Extract specified file to stdout